# Linker error: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, build-error

I have a header1.h included in raster2d.h and then raster2d.h is included in io.cpp and in raster2d.cpp. When I compile I get the following linker error`

```
   g++ -g -I. -I/opt/local/include  -o raster2d.o -c raster2d.cpp
   g++ -g -I. -I/opt/local/include  -o stb.o -c stb.cpp
   g++ -g -I. -I/opt/local/include  -o io.o -c io.cpp
   g++ -o raster2d raster2d.o SimpleImage.o stb.o io.o  -L/opt/local/lib  
   duplicate symbol __ZN9Transform14multiplicationE6Matrix in:
       raster2d.o
       io.o
   duplicate symbol __ZN9Transform5scaleEP7Point2fff in:
       raster2d.o
       io.o
   duplicate symbol __ZN9Transform6rotateEP7Point2ff in:
       raster2d.o
       io.o
   duplicate symbol __ZN9Transform9translateEP7Point2fff in:
       raster2d.o
       io.o
   ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   make: *** [raster2d] Error 1
```

Transform is a class in header.h
Transform::translate Transform::scale & Transform::rotate are three functions in header1.h

Comment: Did you implement function in a header, that is common for all objects?

Comment: Please show some code :)

Comment: (a) be sure to use include guards and (b) any functions defined in headers need to be inline and/or template functions.